# Mysql doesn't return singular records for plural search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have table like below:

| search_keywords |
| --- |
| book |
| Book |
| books |
| BOOKS |
| men's shirt |
| mens shirt |
| women's shirt |
| womens shirt |

Below query returns all records which is what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("book*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But when user search using plural i.e. books then it doesn't retun record which has singular i.e. book

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("books*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Please note that I have to use fulltext to meet the other criteria like:

1. if user search "hats" or "hat", it should return same records
2. if user search "books" or "book", it should return same records
3. "men's shirt" should only return men's shirt and not the women's search
4. "shirt" should return men shirt as well as women shirt etc.
5. "womens shirt" or "women's shirt" should return same record but it should not return the "mens shirt"

That is why I can't use the like statement.

what i have tried:

***NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE :***

```
 SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("book" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
 SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("mens shirt" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

***BOOLEAN MODE***

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("+mens +shirt" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But all above break one or more criteria which I am trying to achieve.

So what should I change in my query to meet the all above criteria.

Comment: May something like `SELECT * FROM sale WHERE MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("book*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (search_keywords) AGAINST ("books*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)` be helpful?

Comment: But there is only one search box so how we can generate plural & singular keywords based on user's input? Assume user search "men shirt" then "men shirts" or user search "men shirts" then how we will able to convert it into "men shirt". without it we can't generate OR query like you suggested.

Comment: _..."men shirts".....how we will able to convert it into "men shirt"..._ We would store both in column search_keywords. Few years ago this dirty approach did work for me.

Comment: thanks @B001ᛦ for suggestion but i can't use it as my search_keywords is generated dynamically based on some of product's columns i.e. Product Title, Product Category, Product description etc. I have combined all of them in one column and trying to use that  generated column for FULLTEXT search, so i don't have to generate FULLTEXT for all those fields.